# Javascript json object

Tags: javascript

I have one object and one `auditTrack` object that will keep changed data info for every key of object:

```
var oldObject = {
"type":"foundation",
  "yards":"10",
  "active":true
}

var auditTrack={
"active":'{"0":{"previous":true,"current":true,"timestamp":"2018-07-05T12:55:29.337Z"}}',
"yards":'{"0":{"previous":10,"current":10,"timestamp":"2018-07-05T12:55:29.337Z"}}',
"type":'{"0":{"previous":"foundation","current":"foundation","timestamp":"2018-07-05T12:55:29.337Z"}}'
}
```

Now my requirement is when `newObject` will have change value needed to add in `auditTrack` Object:

```
ex-- var newObj ={
"type":"foundation",
  "yards":"10",
  "active":true
}//here type changed and yards changed so need to add in auditTrack object like that
```

I want my `auditObject` should be as follows:

```
var auditTrack={
"active":'{"0":{"previous":true,"current":true,"timestamp":"2018-07-05T12:55:29.337Z"}}',
"yards":'{"0":{"previous":10,"current":10,"timestamp":"2018-07-05T12:55:29.337Z"}},{"1":{"previous":10,"current":20,"timestamp":"2018-07-05T12:55:29.337Z"}}',
"type":'{"0":{"previous":"foundation","current":"foundation","timestamp":"2018-07-05T12:55:29.337Z"},{"1":{"previous":"foundation","current":"zen","timestamp":"2018-07-05T12:55:29.337Z"}}}'

}
```

Here is my code I tried:

```
for (var key in auditTrack) {
  if (typeof auditTrack[key] === 'string') {
    console.log(JSON.parse(auditTrack[key]));
    let keys = Object.keys(JSON.parse(auditTrack[key]));

    if (JSON.parse(auditTrack[key])[keys.length - 1].current != newObj[key]) {
      var newObj2 = {
        "previous": JSON.parse(auditTrack[key])[keys.length - 1].current,
        "current": pour[key],
        "timestamp": new Date().toISOString()
      };
      console.log("new " + JSON.stringify(newObj2));
      JSON.parse(auditTrack[key])[1] = newObj2;

      console.log(auditTrack);
    }
  }
}

console.log("helloo " + JSON.stringify(auditTrack));
```

Comment: Can you show the code you have tried thus far?

Comment: [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Answer (score 0):

Just compare your data e.g

```
if(newObj.yards !== auditTrack.yards[auditTrack.yards.length -1]) {
...push new data
}
```

Also you have to make your properties in `auditTrack` as `Array` and convert to `JSON` object if not already.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want something like that.

Create instance from jsObject with consturctor properties and change any property and check your instance auditTrack property. Like this;

```
var instance = new jsObject("foundation",10,active);
console.log(instance.auditTrack);
instance.type = "organization";
console.log(instance.auditTrack);

  function jsObject(type,yards,active){

  this._type = type ? type : "unknown";
  this._yards = yards ? yards : 0;
  this._active = active ? true : false;


  this.auditTrack = {
     type : [],
     yards : [],
     active : [],
  };

    this.constructor();
}

jsObject.prototype = {
    constructor : function() {
    this.auditTrack.type.push({key:0, previous:undefined,current:this.type,timeStamp:new Date()});
        this.auditTrack.yards.push({key:0, previous:undefined,current:this.yards,timeStamp:new Date()});
        this.auditTrack.active.push({key:0, previous:undefined,current:this.active,timeStamp:new Date()});
  },
  get type(){
    return this._type;
  },
  set type(value) {
        this.auditTrack.type.push({key:this.auditTrack.type.length,previous:this._type,current:value, timeStamp:new Date()});
        this._type = value;
  },
  get yards(){
    return this._yards;
  },
  set yards(value) {
        this.auditTrack.type.push({key:this.auditTrack.yards.length,previous:this._yards,current:value, timeStamp:new Date()});
        this._yards = value;
  },
  get active(){
    return this._active;
  },
  set active(value) {
        this.auditTrack.type.push({key:this.auditTrack.active.length, previous:this._active,current:value, timeStamp:new Date()});
        this._active = value;
  }
}
```